# How to iterate big data from PostgreSQL through Hibernate to Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hadoop, bigdata

I have to iterate large count of rows of Hibernate query.

I write a class, that implements `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat`.

Firstly, I've tried to get batches via `OFFSET/LIMIT`. After the second million of iterations process has become very slowly.

Secondary, I've tried to apply iterating via `org.hibernate.ScrollableResults`, but initializing of this query was too long.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Entity.class).setReadOnly(true)
                .setCacheable(false).setFetchSize(1000);

ScrollableResults scroll = criteria.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

What can I do else?

I can't do it without ORM, my app has a lot of business logic.

Comment: Are you making sure that each batch using offset/limit clears the session cache?  If not, that could be the reason for the slower iteration later on.

Comment: @Naros, yes, I have no session cache clearing, But the most of time takes postgres' query. Scanning either table or primary key to offset position takes too mutch time. I'm looking for something about iterator, which is created by postgres.